# Update List A with workflow triggered in List B which looks up data in List A

Tags: workflow, updatelistitems

I have two lists: **People** & **Projects**

**People** list has two items: Man1 & Man2

When I create a **project** I give it a *Project name*: Project1, look up into **People** list and choose *Member1*: Man1, then choose Man2, then choose *Result:* Good or Bad. When I save/change Project item it should start a workflow that updates corresponding items in **People** list and adds number of projects that Man1 and Man2 had, their corresponding results and ideally appends a "Project Name" to an existing text field.

[image]

Can anyone help me to find a right way to do that? I couldn't make it work(((

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Kaylee, here are the [screenshots](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_jmHqmzvJmScnlvNlpzVk95YVk&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

You can use workflow to edit project numbers of the items in the People list when creating an item in the Projects list. But when editing item in the Projects, workflow cannot get the original data of this item, so we cannot plus / minus project number of the item in the People List based on the project item.

We can only update People list when creating an item in the Projects list using workflow.

Additional information about this workflow:

1. You can create “All Projects” as a calculated column, formula: [Good Projects]+[Bad Projects]. Then you should only update “Bad Projects” and “Good Projects” using workflow.
2. In the workflow, you can add condition to check if the Result of Project item is “Good”. If it is good, the “Good Projects” of this user plus 1. If it is “Bad”, the “Bad Projects” of this user plus 1.
   [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create two `"Update list item"` actions in your Projects workflow. The first would update list item in **People** *where* `People Name = Member 1` (inside if condition to verify *Member 1* isn't empty). Then the second would do the same thing for *member 2*.

Comment: [Screenshots](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_jmHqmzvJmScnlvNlpzVk95YVk&usp=sharing)

Comment: I see that workflow (List Workflow) started in workflow list settings, but changes don't apply in People list anyway. I created workflow variable "empty" in order to compare it with member1 or member2.

Comment: What type of fields are `People Name` and `Member 1`? If you're trying to update a `People or group` field with a string, it won't work.